# Electron application Can not find Squirrel

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I build an electron app with auto-update enabled. After running the application on Windows, I got an error emitted by my application which is "Error: Can not find Squirrel".
After look into the code of electron project for finding the error message.

```
  checkForUpdates () {
    const url = this.updateURL;
    if (!url) {
      return this.emitError(new Error('Update URL is not set'));
    }
    if (!squirrelUpdate.supported()) {
      return this.emitError(new Error('Can not find Squirrel'));
    }
    this.emit('checking-for-update');
    squirrelUpdate.checkForUpdate(url, (error, update) => {
      if (error != null) {
        return this.emitError(error);
      }
      if (update == null) {
        return this.emit('update-not-available');
      }
      this.updateAvailable = true;
      this.emit('update-available');
      squirrelUpdate.update(url, (error) => {
        if (error != null) {
          return this.emitError(error);
        }
        const { releaseNotes, version } = update;
        // Date is not available on Windows, so fake it.
        const date = new Date();
        this.emit('update-downloaded', {}, releaseNotes, version, date, this.updateURL, () => {
          this.quitAndInstall();
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

And after check the function `squirrelUpdate.supported()`. I know it is because the install location has no file "Update.exe".

I use electron-builder to generate my application and there is no `Update.exe` in unpacked packaged directory. How do I generate the `Update.exe` file？

The block of configuration of electron-builder in package.json is blow:

```
       "win": {
            "target": [
                "nsis"
            ],
            "defaultArch": "x64",
            "verifyUpdateCodeSignature": false
        },
```

How to solve the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The reason there is no `update.exe` is because you have "nsis" as the target package type.

The auto updater package you are trying to use is meant to be compatible with `Squirrel.Windows`. If you change your target to "squirrel" it will have the `update.exe` you are looking for.

There are additional dependencies required when using `Squirrel.Windows`; see below:

https://www.electron.build/configuration/win